# How to import an H2Database *.db database file into a WAMP server?

Tags: wamp, h2

I made a database using [H2Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), the database file is saved as `*.db` file in my documents,
how to import that `*.db` file to WAMP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty certain you cannot import the `*.db` file directly. But since [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) stands for **W**indows, **A**pache, **M**ySQL and **P**HP you would need to have the actual H2Database database itself converted to SQL so it can easily be imported into MySQL. As per [the following Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3259166/117259), within H2Database database you could run the following command to export the database as SQL:

```
SCRIPT TO '[the target script file to export to]'
```

Of course replacing `[the target script file to export to]` with the actual name of the SQL file you would like to export to. Another option is to use the [script tool](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Script.html#main_String...) like this to export the DB in SQL format:

```
java org.h2.tools.Script -url [database url] -user [username] -password [password] -script [the target script file to export to]
```

Replacing `[database url]` with the actual database URL, `[username]` with the actual username, `[password]` with the actual password and `[the target script file to export to]` with the actual name of the script file you would like to export to.